# Import Error: DLL load failed The specified procedure could not be found (WinDBG on XP)

Tags: python, windows, windbg, pykd

I am using a package called pykd(https://pykd.codeplex.com/) which is an extension for Windbg. I downloaded this on windows and everything works fine. However, when downloading this on a Windows XP everything is normal. It is installs ok, and everything seems to be fine. However, when I run my python program, it gets stuck and gives the following error.
[image]

Can someone explain to me what this error means? Why is this error occurring in Windows XP but not windows 7? I am running python 2.7. The code it is giving the error in is below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is pykd version? The last pykd builds don't support XP, sorry. The error means pykd.pyd module cannot be loaded on WinXP.

You can try note old pykd version to install:

```
pip install pykd<0.3.1.0
```